# GIT workspace synced in multiple system

Tags: eclipse, git, synchronization, workspace

**GIT workspace synced in multiple system**

Is it possible to have the same git workspace , in multiple system.

Say for example I have a workspace in my office system, I want to carry on the task in my personal laptop  after coming home.

Any changes I make in the workspace, adding, deleting , editing java/class files.

will be reflected automatically to the other system

Comment: Automatically is a bad idea.  Just work as you were two developers instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use git, Use branches and commit your code to the desired branch at the end of each day even if your code is not complete.

when you get home fetch the changes `git fetch --all --prune` and you can continue to work from the point you stopped at work.

When you done you can commit your changes with a simple commit or with 
`commit --ammend` and once you done use git squash to align your commit log as you want it to be.

---

In order to do a git squash follow those steps:

```
// X is the number of commits you wish to squash, in your case 6
git rebase -i HEAD~X
```

Once you squash your commits - choose the `s` for squash = it will combine all the commits into a single commit.

[image]

---

You also have the --root flag in case you need it

try: `git rebase -i --root`

**--root**

```
Rebase all commits reachable from <branch>, instead of limiting them with
an <upstream>.

This allows you to rebase the root commit(s) on a branch.  
When used with --onto, it will skip changes already contained in `<newbase>`   
(instead of `<upstream>`) whereas without --onto it will operate on every 
change. When used together with both --onto and --preserve-merges, all root 
commits will be rewritten to have `<newbase>` as parent instead.`
```